# Process two CSV fies to find similar data and write results to 3rd csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am trying to read two CSV files with the data listed below, compare the MAC addresses from each file, if a MAC exists in both files, write the following information to a 3rd CSV file(final.csv)

- mac, interface, vlan, ip

The two input files are:

1. swfile - information from MAC table on switch(mac-address, interface, vlan)
2. rtrfile - information from ARP table on router(mac-address, IP address)

I can run through a single file and get all of the information, but when I add the code to include reading and comparing against the 2nd file, I only get the first mac from the first file, it compares against the MACs in the second file, then it ends.  It does not go through the rest of the MACs in the first file.

This is sample swfile data:

```
00:40:58:0E:28:2E,Gi1/0/50,1
00:40:84:21:26:6A,Gi2/0/36,1
00:4E:01:B3:58:67,Gi2/0/50,1
00:C0:B7:D9:C6:8A,Gi3/0/49,1
00:C0:B7:D9:CD:2B,Gi3/0/48,1
00:C0:B7:D9:CD:87,Gi2/0/49,1
00:C0:B7:F7:BC:9A,Gi1/0/50,1
```

This is sample rtrfile data:

```
00:40:58:0E:28:2E,10.10.10.11
00:40:84:21:26:6A,10.10.10.21
00:4E:01:B3:58:67,10.10.10.95
00:C0:B7:D9:C6:8A,10.10.10.19
00:C0:B7:D9:CD:2B,10.10.10.14
00:C0:B7:D9:CD:87,10.10.10.15
00:C0:B7:F7:BC:9A,10.10.10.16
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
with open(rtrfile, 'r') as rfile:
    rtrreader = csv.reader(rfile, delimiter=',')
    with open(swfile, 'r') as sfile:
        swreader = csv.reader(sfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in rtrreader:
            rmac = row[0]
            for row in swreader:
                smac = row[0]
                if rmac == smac:
                    print("Found: " + rmac + " - " + smac)
```

As I stated, it will read the first MAC from rtrfile, find the matching entry from swfile, print it and then exit.  It will not go back through rtrfile to compare the rest of the mac addresses. How can I fix this and make it so that it will compare all of the MAC addresses from rtrfile with all the addresses in swfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to read both files into a `list` or `dict`, and then iterate over that to produce your output. I prefer a `dict` because that allows us to easily check if the MAC addresses in the second file already exist in the first file.
For example:

```
macinfo = {} # Make an empty dict
with open(swfile, 'r') as sfile:
    swreader = csv.reader(sfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in swreader:
        # row[0] is the MAC address
        # key of the dict is the MAC address. Value is the entire row. 
        macinfo[row[0]] = row 
        
with open(rtrfile, 'r') as rfile:
    rtrreader = csv.reader(rfile, delimiter=',')    
    for row in rtrreader:
        try:
            # row[0] is the MAC address
            # Try to get the row having that MAC address from macinfo
            previously_read_row = macinfo[row[0]] # This line throws a KeyError if not found
            previously_read_row.append(row[1]) # Add the IP address
        except KeyError: # row[0] not found in dict; skip this row
            pass
```

Then, all you need to do is write the values in `macinfo` to the new file.

```
with open(finalfile, "w") as wfile:
    fwriter = csv.writer(wfile, delimiter=",")
    fwriter.writerows(macinfo.values())
```

`finalfile` now contains:

```
00:40:58:0E:28:2E,Gi1/0/50,1,10.10.10.11
00:40:84:21:26:6A,Gi2/0/36,1,10.10.10.21
00:4E:01:B3:58:67,Gi2/0/50,1,10.10.10.95
00:C0:B7:D9:C6:8A,Gi3/0/49,1,10.10.10.19
00:C0:B7:D9:CD:2B,Gi3/0/48,1,10.10.10.14
00:C0:B7:D9:CD:87,Gi2/0/49,1,10.10.10.15
00:C0:B7:F7:BC:9A,Gi1/0/50,1,10.10.10.16
```